# Wordpress show future, scheduled posts

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using a newsletter plugin - meenews to extract my posts.
By default it only gets items that are `Published` and not the future ones.

Ideally I would like to show up and coming events, not ones that have already passed.

Is there a way in my functions.php for my theme that I can tell it to put all posts as published, or what would be a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind - found this plugin 'The Future is now'

Sometimes you just have to ask out loud :P